# How to use vuforia for location based augmented reality

Tags: geolocation, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have a scenario where i need to draw 3D objects based on the geolocations using Augmented Reality. For example there is a path to be drawn from place A to B 3D line has to be drawn from A to B in augmented reality considering all the parameters like direction, altitude, camera direction. Can i use vuforia SDK in this context.

Comment: what's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. Vuforia is not meant for that. You can look at other SDKs -  for example, I believe **mixare** is geo based (and also open source).